# getting info on how the browser passes Kerberos/SPNEGO creds to client side javascript

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, kerberos, client-side, spnego

ok i've just started some webdev and need to get a client-side web application (vue) to grab the credentials.

but the process for this seems to be a bit of a black box - cant really find a lot of information on the net about it apart from stuff like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials):

> When a request's credentials mode (Request.credentials) is include, browsers will only expose the response to the frontend JavaScript code if the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials value is true.

fyi i've tried to build both chrome and firefox so i can maybe debug the execution path.. but failed with this..